# Null Pointer Exception when trying to retrieve data from JTable in Swing

Tags: java, swing, multidimensional-array, nullpointerexception, jtable

I have a JTable and I wish to loop through the rows and columns of that table to retrieve each value and then add that value to a 2D array (matrix). However I get a NullPointerException when the last value in the table is attempted to be extracted. I have the following code:

```
DefaultTableModel dtm = (DefaultTableModel) table.getModel();
        double [][] matrix = new double[rows][cols];
        for(int i=0;i<rows;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<cols;j++){
                matrix[i][j]=Double.parseDouble((String) dtm.getValueAt(i, j));
            }
        }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

```
Error message Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Unknown Source)
at Inverse.actionPerformed(Inverse.java:102)
```

Comment: How are the variables `rows` and `cols` defined and which value do they have?

Comment: Add stacktrace please.

Comment: Rows and Cols are simply defined from a user input from a JOptionPane window

Comment: Are they checked? It seems that the table model returns a `null` value.

Comment: Final table model value always returns null. Values from table model are are integers.

Comment: Does that mean `dtm.getValue(rows-1, cols-1)` returns `null`? `Double.parseDouble(null)` throws a `NullPointerException`!

Comment: Yes the Double.parseDouble(null) is what is throwing the exception but the value being read in from the table is not null. For example if the table is 2 rows by 2 columns with the following entries {1,2},{3,4}, the final value {4} will be null when dtm.getValue(1,1) is called.

Comment: @wilty If you are sure the values is not `null` then try using `dtm.getValueAt(i, j).toSting` and also make check the values is not null to avoid `NPE`

Answer (score 1):

the method

```
dtm.getValueAt(row, column);
```

returns an object not an int
then you are trying to cast an object into a string and then parse to a double
giving you null

try this instead:

```
DefaultTableModel dtm = (DefaultTableModel) table.getModel();
    double [][] matrix = new double[rows][cols];
    for(int i=0;i<rows;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<cols;j++){
            matrix[i][j]=Double.parseDouble(dtm.getValueAt(i,j).toString());
        }

    }
```